# Alternating Select List Option Colours

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

My select list is generated dynamically from my database. I want to have the background colour of each item in the dropdown alternate like this example (from [here](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/design_no19.htm)):

[image: lists]

So basically, I need to alternate the class ofeach option tag, like in the code block below. How would I do this using jQuery since I can't manually write the colours in myself?

```
<FORM>
    <SELECT>
        <OPTION>What is your preferred browser?</OPTION>
        <OPTION class="mar">Explorer 5.5</OPTION>
        <OPTION class="white">Explorer 6.0</OPTION>
        <OPTION class="mar">Netscape 4.7</OPTION>
        <OPTION class="white">Netscape 6.0</OPTION>
        <OPTION class="mar">WebTV</OPTION>
        <OPTION class="white">Lynx</OPTION>
        <OPTION class="mar">Other</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select option:even').css({'background-color': 'red'})
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/My7rj/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need (to source) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), even javascript for that.

```css
option:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: white;
}
```

See documentation for [:nth-child()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) css selector.

Comment: verified in 2022

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:even` and `:odd` selectors:

```
$('#selectId option:even').addClass('class1');
$('#selectId option:odd').addClass('class2');
```